# How can I call an externed template function in C++

Tags: c++, templates, extern

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

I wrote a template function and the call of type int in function main:

```
template <class T> T max (T a, T b) {    }
int main() {
    max(1,2);
}
```

As most of the C++ books said, the `int max(int,int)` function will be generated during the compile time when the compiler meet the `max(1,2)`.

But in another file, I wrote the declaration of the `int max(int,int)` and call it, but the compiler(actually the linker) caught an error said the reference of `max(int,int)` is not found.

```
extern int max(int,int);
max(1,2);    // Error:undefined reference to max(int,int)
```

So , what's the wrong point, and how can I call the max(int,int) function using extern and not a header file declaration.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is only answered a few thousand times. The short form is: You either have to arrange for the template definition to be visible when used such that the compiler can implicitly instantiated the function template or you have to explicitly instantiate the function template.

Note, that the declaration `extern int max(int, int);` declares a non-template function `max()` taking two `int` as parameter. This reference will never be satisfied by a function template, whether it is instantiated or not.

Comment: also the extern keyword basically means "this function it's defined in another file and you shouldn't care about that at compile time"

Comment: If the question has been asked before, why not close it as a duplicate?

Comment: I'm sorry, but when I search the keywords 'template' 'extern' 'function' via google, what I found is only the extern template feature in C++0x, and no one actually solved my problem. I won't search the 'only in header file' when I met with the problem and describe that in an undirect way.

Answer (score 1):

The `extern int max(int,int);` declares a non-template function. It wouldn't match the template, even if that had been visible in your other file.

The correct way is to put the template in a header, and include that everywhere the function is used (or, even better, use the `max` template already available in the standard library).

Answer (score 0):

When you declare `extern int max(int, int)` you tell the compiler that there's a function with this signature defined somewhere, not necessarily in the same translation unit. `extern` is actually redundant, as functions have external linkage by default.

Now, you seem to think that this declaration provides a definition for an instantiation of the template function with T = int. It does not, the two are not related in any way. Plain functions are prefered over function templates when the compiler searches for a candidate for the call `max(1,2)`. When it finds the declaration `int max(int, int)`, it's a perfect match and its job is done - it never even tries to instantiate the template. After compilation is done, the linker is supposed to find the definition, and as you haven't provided it, you get an undefined reference.

So you can either write a definition

```
int max(int, int) { }
```

or explicitly tell the compiler to use a template

```
max<int>(1,2);
```

You can also *specialize* the template for `int` type

```
template<>
int max<int>(int, int) { };
```

but note that if you keep the normal function, it would still be a better match.